# How can I charge three series gel batteries?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, dc, power-electronics

I have 12 V - 24 Ah three gel batteries. I want to charge when they are connected to series and load. These batteries are same. The charging methods same as following:

[image]

Can I charge these gel batteries 42 Voltage / 7.5 - 8 A (DC Voltage Source) when they are connected to series and load?

Comment: Will you be using these batteries as a backup when power fails (standby use, i.e. the charge voltage will normally be present) or will they be regularly charged and discharged (cyclic use)? If the charge voltage will almost always be present, choose a lower voltage of about 13.5-3.6V per cell, 40.5-40.8V in total. This will increaee the lifetime of your batteries.

Comment: While the batteries are charging, they will discharge at the same time. (cyclic use)

Comment: That is not what is meant with cyclic use. What I asked is: Are the batteries regularly discharged by a significant amount (with no charging voltage present) or will the charge voltage almost always be present and will your batteries only rarely be discharged?

Comment: Uh Sorry , yes batteries discharge constantly . Batteries are in continuous use.

Comment: You can't charge and discharge a battery at the same time.  You can have a charger powerful enough to charge the battery and power the load at the same time, though.

Comment: Can i charge and decharge gel battery at the same time if i have powerful enough power supply .